# UUPS Upgrades using Foundry

Tags: contract-development, foundry

I am wondering if any of you have tried to do UUPS smart contract upgrade using Foundry ? Similarly the same way you write a script in hardhat. If so, how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have before and based my deployment script based on this example: https://github.com/jordaniza/OZ-Upgradeable-Foundry/blob/main/script/DeployUUPS.s.sol

Answer (score 0):

The OpenZeppelin team has developed a new library based on Foundry for working with UUPS contracts. Check it here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-foundry-upgrades